# How to shutdown Stanford CoreNLP Redwood logging?

Tags: java, logging, stanford-nlp

How can I shut down the Stanford CoreNLP messages (see end of post)?
I first tried setting `log4j.category.edu.stanford=OFF` in log4j.properties but that didn't help so I found out that apparently it uses a nonstandard logging framework called "Redwood". According to `http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/`there is a documentation but it is password protected. I tried  `RedwoodConfiguration.empty().apply();` but that doesn't help either.

The logging messages:

```
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Loading default properties from tagger edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1,2 sec].
```

P.S.: `Redwood.hideAllChannels();` also doesn't work. The following however suppresses my own logging statement (but not the ones from StanfordCoreNLP):

```
RedwoodConfiguration.empty().apply();
Redwood.log("test redwood");
```

**Solution** Ok, StevenC was right, it weren't logging statements after all but the default initialization messages are written to stderr which I was not expecting seeing that Stanford has it's own logging framework and then doesn't use it :-)

Anyways, his hints led me to discover this solution:

```
// shut off the annoying intialization messages
RedwoodConfiguration.empty().captureStderr().apply();
nlp = new StanfordCoreNLP(myproperties);
// enable stderr again
RedwoodConfiguration.current().clear().apply();
```

Comment: I couldn't find the `captureStderr()` method, so I used the following line `RedwoodConfiguration.empty().capture(System.err).apply()` instead of yours. 

Works perfectly.

Comment: I have less comments but still I have some remaining : 
May 12, 2017 2:36:04 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 83 rules
May 12, 2017 2:36:04 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 267 rules
May 12, 2017 2:36:04 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 25 rules

Comment: Those INFO messages are via Redwood and can be muted by the methods given at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761099/mute-stanford-corenlp-logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also find the Redwood Tutorial PDF on GitHub in the Redwood project.

The url is in this page: https://github.com/gangeli/redwood/blob/master/doc/tutorial.pdf

(Obviously, I can't tell you if the documents are the same, 'cos I don't know the username / password either :-) )

---

Taking this a bit further, the Tutorial PDF I linked to really just a slide show.  If you want documentation of the properties file, the best I could find was the javadocs for the `RedwoodConfiguration.parse` method.  And in fact, the rest of that classes javadoc is probably the best doc that you will find ... short of reading the source code.

Warning ... there are indications that the free-standing Redwood code on GitHub may be different to the version in the NLP codebase.

Comment: All I want to do is just to shut off logging :-)

Comment: You could always read the source code (for the NLP embedded version) ... :-)

Comment: Actually, are you sure those are logging messages, and not random `System.out` or `System.err` messages?  The Redwood logging config API allows you to capture those message and send them to the logs.  And of course, you should be able to send the logs to "/dev/null" or some such.  This is in the javadocs.

Comment: `RedwoodConfiguration.current().clear().apply();
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);`  works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

StanfordNLP uses `Redwood` as logging framework for logging. You have to disable it before initializing StanfordNLP pipeline.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging.RedwoodConfiguration;
RedwoodConfiguration.current().clear().apply();
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

It works for me. It does not show lengthy INFO message in every line, while running program.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by setting blank Output Stream to System error stream.

Please see my answer in similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/48743963/1303210