# How to suppress Stanford CoreNLP Redwood logging in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, logging, stanford-nlp

The thread [How to shutdown Stanford CoreNLP Redwood logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851217/how-to-shutdown-stanford-corenlp-redwood-logging) supposedly resolved my question in Java. I would like to do the same in MATLAB, but the code(s) given in that thread doesn't work. Please suggest a complete solution, starting with what to import, setting properties, etc.

My code is the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

tagger = MaxentTagger('./english-left3words-distsim.tagger');
```

which logs on the command line:

```
Reading POS tagger model from ./english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [3.6 sec].
```

taken from CreateTagger.m in my package:
https://github.com/jzsfvss/POSTaggerSML.

Comment: You mean that you tried to run the following code under Matlab right? `import edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging.RedwoodConfiguration; RedwoodConfiguration.current().clear().apply(); pipeline = StanfordCoreNLP(props);`

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Yes, I tried that. But props is being interpreted as some variable, so a value would need to be assigned. I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very up on calling Java from MatLab, but I think it would work and remove the loading message to use instead the following (where the final `false` argument says to not print loading):

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils;

...
tagger = MaxentTagger('./english-left3words-distsim.tagger', StringUtils.argsToProperties({'-model', './english-left3words-distsim.tagger'}), false);
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps the easiest thing would be to make an slf4j config file `simplelogger.properties` with the line:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger=warn
```

and to make sure that file is on the Java classpath (presumably with a call to `javaaddpath`) so that the tagger component no longer prints INFO messages like the file loading.

Comment: The first one gives the error:  
`No method 'argsToProperties' with matching signature found for class 'edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils'.`  
  
The second one added as:  
`org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger = warn;
javaaddpath('./simplelogger.properties');`  
gives the error:  
`Undefined function or variable 'warn'.`

Comment: The first solution worked once I added `{ }` around the `StringUtils.argsToProperties` arguments, because it expected an input of type `String[]`. I updated the GitHub package.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer to include that fix to the first solution!